# Увеличение производительности БД Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, nosql

Есть 2 сервера на одном 64 гигов оперативы на втором 128. Есть БД, в которую каждый день пишется десяток тысяч записей в одну таблицу, и каждую минуту из этой таблицы идет селект. Когда таблица дошла до полутора миллиона записей, селект стал выполняться очень долго. Таблица может и будет расти и я переживаю, что б на 5 миллионах записей все не лягло. Оперативная память на серверах практически не используется. Куда копать что бы избавиться от этой проблемы?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111870/discussion-on-question-by-alexander-fomenko----mys).